# Which fmt option in numpy.savetxt keeps infinite integer precision?

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I have been using `numpy.savetxt` without specifying the `fmt` option, and sometimes when a particularly large integer is supposed to be saved, it is recorded with an `e` notation as a floating point number of some finite precision.
I would like all integers, no matter how many digits, to be recorded lossless, simply including all digits.
However, reading through the [format documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)  it is not clear to me which `fmt` choice will result in lossless integer storage.

What is the appropriate `fmt` setting I should use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `'%s'` or `'%r'`, which simply call `str` or `repr` on the elements of your array respectively.

Also, you're reading the wrong format string documentation. (It's the format string documentation the `numpy.savetxt` docs link to, but it's still wrong.) `numpy.savetxt` uses old-school `%` formatting, documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting).

Answer (score 1):

```
In [53]: arr = np.array([1.232, 1.232423423234235352352535235253])                                   
In [54]: arr.dtype                                                                                   
Out[54]: dtype('float64')
In [55]: arr                                                                                         
Out[55]: array([1.232     , 1.23242342])
```

`savetxt` iterates on the 'rows' of your array, and formats each with `fmt`:

```
In [56]: tuple(arr)                                                                                  
Out[56]: (1.232, 1.2324234232342353)
In [57]: '%f, %.16f'%tuple(arr)                                                                      
Out[57]: '1.232000, 1.2324234232342353'
```

The action in [57] is straight forward Python formatting.  `savetxt` docs summarizes this formatting, with a link to the full Python docs.

oops - I demoed a float; you want an integer.  `int64` is the max integer dtype.  `object` dtype can hold python integers when can be longer.

====

The largest numeric dtype is `np.int64`:

```
Out[86]: array([               1232, 1232423423234235352])
In [87]: arr.dtype                                                                                   
Out[87]: dtype('int64')
In [88]: '%g, %d'%tuple(arr)                                                                         
Out[88]: '1232, 1232423423234235352'
```

Larger integers are stored as Python integer objects.  Math with such arrays is not as fast, and is incomplete.

```
In [89]: arr = np.array([1232, 1232423423234235352999])                                              
In [90]: arr                                                                                         
Out[90]: array([1232, 1232423423234235352999], dtype=object)
In [91]: '%g, %d'%tuple(arr)                                                                         
Out[91]: '1232, 1232423423234235352999'
```